# Make firework looking circles in four different directions

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make the circles spawn into four different directions, so far I got this:

[image]

But I want it to go into four direction and have a shape a little thinner like I've drawn her with the red lines:

[image]

My code looks like this

```js
        var points = [];
    
    function tegnSirkler(){
        var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
        var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
        context.fillStyle = "black";
        context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    
        for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++){
            
            var farge = "#" + Math.random().toString(16).substr(-6);
            var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 300 / 2.1);
            var y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 300 / 2.1);
            var radius = 2;
            
            points.push(x);
            points.push(y);
            
            console.log("Flyttet et punkt i plass" + x + "," + y + ",");
            console.log("Lagt til et punkt i plass" + x + "," + y + ",");
            console.log("Tegnet et punkt i plass" + x + "," + y + ",");
        
            context.fillStyle = farge;
            context.fill();
            context.beginPath();
            context.arc(x, y, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2);
            context.stroke();
        }   
    }
    
    function init(){
        setInterval(tegnSirkler, 100);
    }
    
    window.onload = init;
```

```html
            <canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
```

Comment: Well then, it seems you need a fully fledged (even if very simple) particle system. In it, each particle has it's own lifespan, colour, position and velocity. By initialising the particles from one of 4 locations (the emitters) you'll get the effect you're after. I left a couple of answers here you could probably make use of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39673387/having-trouble-calculating-direction-for-particle-explosion/39738548#39738548

Comment: I'm playing around with the answer you had with the particle explosion. It has plenty of things I've never seen before as a complete beginner programmer, but maybe I'll learn and figure out something by doing so :)

Comment: Hope it's of _some_ use to you. We all stand on the shoulders of those that came before us.